# Do "ici aussi" sound awkward together?

Tags: ordre-des-mots

In the following sentence...

> Il est beau ici aussi pendant la saison de Noël.

Does the phrase "ici aussi" sound awkward to you? Would *aussi* be better placed somewhere else, such as the end of the sentence?

Or, au contraire, is the sentence perfectly natural?

Comment: Il est here is quite awkward here, rather than ici aussi...

Comment: "Faut-il qu'on soit seul sur terre, [ici aussi](https://vimeo.com/92835757) ?"

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about the weather, you should say *il fait beau* instead. Then, *il fait beau ici aussi pendant la saison de Noël* sounds natural. You can also say *il fait aussi beau ici pendant la saison de Noël*, but then the meaning is slightly different: it means *the weather is just as nice here*, where you stress how the two weather conditions are exactly as nice in the two places you are comparing.

Comment: Au contraire, I am talking about the visual beauty of the Christmas season, with all the lights and decorations. Winter here is rather very cold!

Comment: Ah ok ! Then "il est beau" is maybe not appropriate either, the "il" must replace a masculine singular noun that precedes, such as "le temps", "le quartier", etc. *Il est beau* to talk about the surroundings in general (as in *it's nice in Winter here*) is unclear, a French native would ask you who is the "il". Maybe you can give the preceding sentence, to see how it would fit ? And another note, "il fait beau" in French means the sky is blue, and that there is no rain, it does not really give a judgment on the temperature. You can definitely say *il fait beau, mais très froid !*

Comment: @ktm5124 In order to express this idea of "beau ici aussi", you can say, for instance: « ***Avec toutes les décos de Noël allumées, c'est un ravissement pour les yeux. Comme c'est beau ici ! On a rien à envier aux autres villes.*** »

Comment: @Greg Would "C'est beau" be better then? Would that sound natural?

Comment: *C'est beau* would definitely be better, but you would need to make sure that this *ce* refers to something mentioned before, or that it is obvious from the context. *Viens visiter New York, c'est beau ici aussi pendant la saison de Noël* is OK, because the *ce* means New York and everything you would see in the city. Hence, I still recommend you give the preceding sentence, to see how it would fit.